# Saving array to database cakephp

Tags: arrays, database, cakephp

I have a form that has multiple entries to the same table, the problem I'm having is that it only sends the last entry to the database and doesn't send the rest. I have used the debug and it only prints out the last field in the form.

With each iteration of `field` its meant to input into the `fields_invoices` table a `invoice_id, field_id, entered_value`

Here is my form

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('FieldsInvoice'); ?>
    <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('FieldsInvoice.id'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->hidden('FieldsInvoice.field_id', array('default' =>$field['Field']['id'])); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('FieldsInvoice.invoice_id', array('default' =>$invoice_id, 'type'=>'hidden')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->Input('FieldsInvoice.entered_value',  array('label'=>$field['Field']['name'], 'default' =>$field['Field']['default_value'])); ?>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->End('Submit');?>
```

Here is the related controller

```
    public function create($id)
    {   
    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Create Invoice');
    $this->set('stylesheet_used', 'homestyle');
    $this->set('image_used', 'eBOXLogoHome.png');   
    $this->layout='home_layout';


     if (!is_numeric($id)) throw new BadMethodCallException('I need an ID');
     $this->Invoice->id = $id;
     if (!$this->Invoice->exists()) throw new NotFoundException('Invalid ID');

    $this->set('invoice_id',$id);

    $names = $this->Invoice->find('list',array(
    'fields'=>array('template_id'),
    'conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));

    $fields = $this->Field->find('all', array(
      'conditions'=>array(
     'template_id'=>$names)));

    $this->set(compact('fields'));
    $this->set(compact('invoice_id'));

    $this->set('name',$names);
    $this->Invoice->create();
    if(empty($this->data)){
        $this->data= $this->Field->read($id);
    } 
    else{
        if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            //die(debug($this->data));

            $this->Invoice->create();
            if($this->FieldsInvoice->save($this->request->data, array('deep'=>true)));
            {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The field has been updated');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'invoices', 'action'=>'index'));

            }
            //else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Could not be saved');
            //}
        }
    }
}









\app\Controller\InvoicesController.php (line 134)
array(
    'FieldsInvoice' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'field_id' => '0',
            'invoice_id' => '97',
            'entered_value' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'field_id' => '99',
            'invoice_id' => '97',
            'entered_value' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'field_id' => '999',
            'invoice_id' => '97',
            'entered_value' => '3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'field_id' => '9999',
            'invoice_id' => '97',
            'entered_value' => '4'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To post multiple fields, use:

```
foreach ($fields as $idx => $field):
    echo $this->Form->hidden('FieldsInvoice.'.$idx.'.id');   
    echo $this->Form->hidden('FieldsInvoice.'.$idx.'.field_id', ...);
    ...
```

and then use `$this->FieldsInvoice->saveMany()` (instead of `->save()`) to save multiple records.

Comment: you forgot some dots. For instance, `3entered_value` in your debug means that you wrote `'FieldsInvoice.'.$idx.'entered_value'` instead of `'FieldsInvoice.'.$idx.'.entered_value'`.

Comment: updated with new array printout, however its now not saving anything to my databse.

Comment: [Read the manual!](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array) Use `$this->FieldsInvoice->save($this->request->data['FieldsInvoice']`

Comment: Right. It should have been `saveMany()` instead of `save()` in my last comment. `saveAll` also works but is deprecated I think.